# Nested Recycler Views, Vertically Scrolled ( Parent using Pagination )

Tags: kotlin

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rv_sales_report"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                android:paddingHorizontal="10dp"
                android:paddingBottom="120dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/mtv_sales_report_date"
                tools:listitem="@layout/item_reportings_new" />
```

```
  <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rv_dynamic_inner_reporting"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/mtv_date_dynamic"
                tools:listitem="@layout/item_inner_reporting" />
```

The inner recycler view is not scrolling I have tried many solutions, non helped me, how can I make the inner recycler view scroll vertically, they both scroll vertically.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Issue is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is solved by showing only four items in the inner Recycler View, and enabling nestedScrollView = true, also handling OnTouch Events for the parent Recycler View.

Answer (score 0):

`android:layout_height="0dp"` You shouldn't use this without setting either the layout weight or without constraining both the top and bottom of the view because without constraints, it might just act as `wrap_content` basically extending beyond the screen.

Also, for the inner view, if the orientation is vertical, then height shouldn't be `wrap_content` maybe changing that would help.

Also, just a tip, having both recycler be vertical is a bad idea because how would android (or the user) know which view you are scrolling on if they are together.

Comment: Thank you, for your help first of all, second of all regarding the two recycler views are in vertical scroll, that an issue we are facing with our UI/UX designers, they still don't have the experience for implementing nice designs and a good flow for our mobile applications.

Comment: hmm, makes sense. Also, did it solve the issue you had?

Comment: The issue is not solved but still I am trying to implement it with real data not dummy, to check if there is an issue.